# How to flip the definition of edges(1) and edges(end) for the histc function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, histogram

In MATLAB:

```
n = histc(x,edges);
```

is defined to behave as follows:

> n(k) counts the value x(i) if edges(k)
>   <= x(i) < edges(k+1). The last bin
>   counts any values of x that match
>   edges(end).

Is there any way to flip the end behavior such that n(1) counts any values of x that match edges(1), and n(end) counts the values x(i) that satisfy edges(end-1) <= x(i) < edges(end)?

Comment: @alian: It looks like we came across some confusion regarding what you want. If n(1) counts values of x that match edges(1), then should those values also be counted in the second bin? They will be if you use the formula edges(k-1) <= x(i) < edges(k) for n(k). You could either move the equal sign to the other side for all bins, or just change the formula for the second bin to edges(k-1) < x(i) < edges(k).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code:

```
n = histc(x, [edges(1) edges]);
n(1) = sum(x==edges(1));
n(end) = [];
```

According to the question posted, the above will return:

- n(1): counts any values of x that match `edges(1)`
- n(k) [k~=1]: counts the value x(i) if `edges(k-1) <= x(i) < edges(k)`

This different from [gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557425/how-to-flip-the-definition-of-edges1-and-edgesend-for-the-histc-function-in-m/1557540#1557540) solution in that his answer uses the bounds: `edges(k-1) < x(i) <= edges(k)` (note the position of the equality sign).

---

To demonstrate, consider this simple example:

```
x = [0 1 1.5 2 2.5 4 6.5 8 10];
edges = 0:2:10;

>> n = fliplr(histc(-x,-fliplr(edges)))
n =
     1     3     2     0     2     1
```

> corresponding to the intervals:
>   0 (0,2] (2,4] (4,6] (6,8] (8,10]

Against:

```
>> n = histc(x, [edges(1) edges]);
>> n(1) = sum(x==edges(1));
>> n(end) = []
n =
     1     3     2     1     1     1
```

> corresponding to the intervals:
>   0 [0,2) [2,4) [4,6) [6,8) [8,10)

Comment: @Amro: There's an error in your binning if you go through by hand. `n(1)` bins the value `0`, while `n(2)` bins the values '0, 1, 1.5`, and `n(end)` bins the value `8`. Notice that the zeroes get counted in two bins, and the 10 never gets counted. If you add more zeroes to `x`, you'll see the bin counts are off.

Comment: I am aware of that... note that I am following exactly what the OP described: that bin k is bounded by edge(k-1) inclusive and edge(k) exclusive.

Comment: in the end, it depends on where you intend the equality sign to be (left or right)

Comment: @Amro: While it's true that that appears to be what the OP originally *asked for*, I'm guessing that it may have been an oversight on their part. They may not have considered that their definition in the question may cause some values to be counted twice in the first two bins.

Comment: gnovice is correct, i was sloppy in phrasing my question, for which i apologize, first time on this board...

Answer (score 0):

Since the `edges` argument has to have monotonically nondecreasing values, one way to flip the edge behavior is to negate and flip the `edges` argument and negate the values for binning. If you then flip the bin count output from [HISTC](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html), you should see the typical edge behavior of HISTC reversed:

```
n = fliplr(histc(-x,-fliplr(edges)));
```

The above uses [FLIPLR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fliplr.html), so `x` and `edges` should be row vectors (i.e. 1-by-N). This code will bin data according to the following criteria:

- The first bin `n(1)` counts any values of `x` that match `edges(1)`.
- The other bins `n(k)` count the values `x(i)` such that `edges(k-1) < x(i) <= edges(k)`.

**Note that this flips the edge behavior of *all* the bins, not just the first and last bins!** The *typical* behavior of HISTC for bin `n(k)` uses the equation `edges(k) <= x(i) < edges(k+1)` (Note the difference between the indices and which side has the equals sign!).

---

**EDIT:** After some discussion...

If you *instead* wanted to bin data according to the following criteria:

- The first bin `n(1)` counts any values of `x` that match `edges(1)`.
- The second bin `n(2)` counts the values `x(i)` such that `edges(1) < x(i) < edges(2)`.
- The other bins `n(k)` count the values `x(i)` such that `edges(k-1) <= x(i) < edges(k)`.

Then the following should accomplish this:

```
n = histc(x,[edges(1) edges(1)+eps(edges(1)) edges(2:end)]);
n(end) = [];
```

The first bin should capture only values equal to `edges(1)`, while the lower edge of the second bin should start at an incremental value above `edges(1)` (found using the [EPS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html) function). The last bin, which counts the number of values equal to `edges(end)`, is thrown out.