# Dividing a range into bins in matlab

Tags: matlab, range, histogram, bins

I have the following range from a much larger matrix :

range(a)

ans =

```
94   153   144    59    79    90   131    64
```

My professor is asking us to:  Divide the range into N = 10 equal-length segments (hereafter called “bins”), and for each bin, find its bounds (aj, bj) as well as its center cj.

(5) Place each measured bacterial count xi into that bin whose lower bound is less than or equal to xi and whose upper bound is greater than xi; thereafter, for each bin count the number of xi assigned to it (= nj).

(6) Plot a histogram of the measured bacterial counts using N = 10 bars.
Try the MATLAB functions hist(x,N) and bar(c, n)

I know this is a lot, but I have absolutely no instruction from this guy and would really appreciate a helping hand :)

Comment: See this answer & video: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013913/matlab-transform-continuous-data-to-discrete-data/7014168#7014168

Comment: you also could check out the answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657719/how-to-display-labels-above-a-histogram-bin

Answer (score 8):

Consider the following example, it should solve all your points:

```
%# random data vector of integers
M = randi([50 200], [100 1]);

%# compute bins
nbins = 10;
binEdges = linspace(min(M),max(M),nbins+1);
aj = binEdges(1:end-1);     %# bins lower edge
bj = binEdges(2:end);       %# bins upper edge
cj = ( aj + bj ) ./ 2;      %# bins center

%# assign values to bins
[~,binIdx] = histc(M, [binEdges(1:end-1) Inf]);

%# count number of values in each bin
nj = accumarray(binIdx, 1, [nbins 1], @sum);

%# plot histogram
bar(cj,nj,'hist')
set(gca, 'XTick',binEdges, 'XLim',[binEdges(1) binEdges(end)])
xlabel('Bins'), ylabel('Counts'), title('histogram of measured bacterial')
```

Note that this correctly handles the last bin (read this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557425/how-to-flip-the-definition-of-edges1-and-edgesend-for-the-histc-function-in) for a discussion on those edge cases)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It gives me an error that says: 

??? Error using ==> accumarray
Third input SZ must be a full row vector with one element for each column of
SUBS.

Error in ==> EE300Project1 at 29
nj = accumarray(binIdx, 1, [nbins ], @sum);

Comment: @patrick.belon: it looks to me you are missing a `1` in there: `nj = accumarray(binIdx, 1, [nbins 1], @sum);`. This also can be simplified as just: `nj = accumarray(binIdx, 1);`

Comment: @patrick.belon: you should edit your question and post the code you are using. I suspect you are doing something wrong as my example above works just fine...

Comment: @Amro, thanks for the examples. it seems to be that the code only works for positive integer numbers, right? what if we have in our data `0's` (i.e. `min(M)==0`)?

Comment: @Tin: no, it should work for any a vector of numbers (positive/negative, integers/floats). A `0` value in the vector isn't treated any differently..

Comment: @Amro, I fixed the problem: `[~, bin_idx] = histc( X, [-Inf,bin_centers(1:end-1), Inf] );`, note that I added `-Inf`

Comment: @Tin: well that's not the same thing, you are using **bin centers** while `histc` expects **bin edges** (read [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html))... The ranges specified by the edges are in the form `[lower,upper)` (lower bound inclusive). I used the centers only for plotting purposes (`bar` function call)... Read my code again :)

Comment: ok thanks. @Demetris you can do this `nj = accumarray(binIdx(:), 1, [nbins 1]);` to handle both row/column vectors as input.

Answer (score 3):

computing histogram:

```
range = [94   153   144    59    79    90   131    64]
[n,xout] = hist(range, 10)
```

`xout` is bin centers, `n` bin counts.

plotting bar graph:

```
 bar(xout,n)
```

computing bin edges:

```
width = xout(2)-xout(1)
xoutmin = xout-width/2
xoutmax = xout+width/2
```